# Change column names except for certain columns

Tags: python, dataframe

Assuming I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'ID': ['AB01'],
            'Col A': ["Yes"],
            'Col B': ["L"],
            'Col C': ["Yes"],
            'Col D': ["L"],
            'Col E': ["Yes"],
            'Col F': ["L"],
            'Type': [85] 
    }
    )
```

I want to change all column names by changing it lowercase, replace space with underscore and adding string `_filled` to the end of name, except for columns named in list `skip = ['ID', 'Type']`.

How can I achieve this? I want the end resulting dataframe to have column names as `ID, col_a_filled, col_b_filled......,Type`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) along with a dict comprehension to get a nice one-liner:

```py
df = df.rename(columns={col:col.lower().replace(" ", "_")+"_filled" for col in df.columns if col not in skip})
```

Comment: I want to change the column names(apart from the ones in `skip`) to lowercase too

Comment: My bad, missed that part. Should it be `col_A_filled` (as in your example) or `col_a_filled` (all lowercase)?

Comment: It should be `col_a_filled`

Comment: I've updated my answer and the example from your post to match the "all lowercase" requirement.